# ViewPager no swipe issue

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm tring to create a ViewPager non-swipable. I've wrote this code

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    ViewPagerAdattatore adattatoreViewPager;
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedIstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedIstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        viewPager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        drawerLayout=(DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.navDrawer);
        listaNavDrawer=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listaDrawer);
        adattatoreViewPager=new ViewPagerAdattatore(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adattatoreViewPager);

    }

}
```

**ViewPagerAdattatore**

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class ViewPagerAdattatore extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public final static int PAGINE=1;

    Fragment fragment;

    public ViewPagerAdattatore(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (arg0) {
        case 0: return new HomePage();
        case 1: return new Informazioni();
        // case 3: return new TerzaPagina();
        }
        fragment=new HomePage();

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return PAGINE;
    }

}
```

Informazioni

```
public class Informazioni extends Fragment {

    TextView textView;
    View view;

    public View onCreateView(Bundle savedIstanceState, LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent) {
        view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_page, parent, false);
        textView=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textView.setText("welcome");

        return view;
    }

}
```

HomePage as the same code of informazioni

**ViewPagerNoSwipe**

```
public class ViewPagerNoSwipe extends ViewPager {

    public ViewPagerNoSwipe(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ViewPagerNoSwipe(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent arg0) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**activity_main**

```
<?XML version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/navDrawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.mypackage.name.utils.ViewPagerNoSwipe
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />    

    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/listaDrawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#2F2F2F"/> 

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**HomePage layout**

```
<?XML version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

when I execute this code I don't see the TextView! why? where is the error(s) in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this-

```
    public class Informazioni extends Fragment {

    TextView textView;
    View view;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)            
    {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_page, container, false);
        textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textView.setText("welcome");
        return view;
    }

}
```

Comment: In your case order of the arguments in **onCreateView** method wrong.

Comment: Thanks it works. I never imagined that it was important to put the arguments with a specific order, I thought it was important to put it simply, without a defined order. Thanks again. I will accept your answer between two minutes

Comment: Mine pleasure to help you.